# SQLite Database: Error inserting name,adress,phonenumber

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am working on a simple SQLite database for my android app. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/). using this tutorial I am trying to add three string values to my database namely "name", "adress" and "phonenumber".

This is the code for DatabaseHandler.java

```
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "favouritesmanager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "favourites";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
private static final String KEY_ADRESS = "adress";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + KEY_ADRESS + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new contact
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone Number
    values.put(KEY_ADRESS, contact.getAdress()); //address

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values); << Error here
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}


// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setAdress(cursor.getString(3));

            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

}
```

and Contact.java class

```
public class Contact {

    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phone_number;
    String _adress;

    public Contact(){

    }

    // constructor
    public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number, String adress){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
        this._adress = adress;
    }

   // constructor
    public Contact(String name, String _phone_number, String adress){
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
        this._adress = adress;
    }

    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._phone_number;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
        this._phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    //getting adress
    public String getAdress(){

        return this._adress;
    }

    //setting adress
    public void setAdress(String adresstowrite){
        this._adress = adresstowrite;
    }
}
```

Below is the code where I am putting data into the database

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
 db.addContact(new Contact(registeredname,registerdphone,adress )); << Error here
```

All of these three variables are Strings.

But when I run the app and check the android monitor it shows following errors

```
    E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=yy adress=checking adress phone_number=08335565
                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table favourites has no column named adress (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO favourites(name,adress,phone_number) VALUES (?,?,?)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:908)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1527)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1399)
                                                                     at digiart.mapwithfirebase.DatabaseHandler.addContact(DatabaseHandler.java:67) // here
                                                                     at digiart.mapwithfirebase.MapsActivity.favourite(MapsActivity.java:301) // and here
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error (missing comma) in the `SQL` create script on `onCreate` method and the `KEY_ADRESS` column is not created.

```
 + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + KEY_ADRESS + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Should be:

```
 + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT, " + KEY_ADRESS + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Comment: Yes it worked. The only thing I had to do is to first uninstall the previous version of app and reinstall as I added a new column to database